# 500 Internal Server Error in subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, drupal

I'm working on trying to add new web site on subdomain but I'm getting Internal Server Error.

When I remove .htaccess from root folder subdomain site is working but current site brokes down.

.htaccess in root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule   ^$     app/     [L]
        RewriteRule   (.*)   app/$1   [L]
    </IfModule>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to setup .htaccess and make current site working and site on subdomain.

New website is in Drupal. Current web site is Cakephp

Update:

error_log

```
RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored
```

Comment: Don't guess at your problem. Read the Apache error_log and it will tell you the reason for the 500 error so you can fix it.

Comment: [Wed Feb 03 16:04:21 2016] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.

Comment: You obviously have more code in your .htaccess code then you are showing. How can anyone help you if you're not posting **all** of your code,

Comment: I think there actually *another* `.htaccess` file that's not being shown here. Perhaps the one in the `app` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed adding this in my root .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?example.com$
    RewriteRule   ^$             app/webroot/     [L]
    RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?example.com$
    RewriteRule   (.*)           app/webroot/$1   [L]
</IfModule>
```